# Difficulty writing a function whithin a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the Guardian API for a project to create a small News based web application to display content on a single page. I am mainly struggling with quoting in JavaScript when trying to write a function whithin a string. Based on the results the information should populate a card with the thumbnail, headline etc.

This is the script.

```
        const GetNews = async (page) => {

            console.log('Retrieving News Articles...')
            var url = 'https://content.guardianapis.com/search?' +
                      ' from-date=2023-01-01&' +
                      'to-date=2024-01-05&' +
                      'show-fields=trailText%2Cheadline%2Cthumbnail&' +
                      'page=' +page+
                      '&' +
                      'q=Sport&' +
                      [API Key]

            var req = new Request(url);

            let response = {"response":...}
                console.log(response)
            let str = ''
            for (let item of response.results) {
                str = str + '<div class="card my-4 mx-4" style="width: 20.5rem;">\
                             <img src= '${item.thumbnail}' class="card-img-top" alt="Card image cap">\
                             <div class="card-body">\
                             <h5 class="card-title">'${item.headline}'</h5>\
                             <p class="card-text">'${item.trailText}'</p>\
                             <a href="${item.webUrl}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>\
                             </div>\
                             </div>'
        }
```

[image: Underlining errors]

I have tried different syntax but I don't know if I am writing it incorrectly, it is to be noted that I am relatively inexperienced with JavaScript.

From following videos I have seen people write these expressions normally and they appear a different colour to signify they are seperate from the quotes, but after researching I have read the $ operator can only be used with single quotes hence why I wrote the code this way.

Comment: you need to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) if you want to use `${....}`

Comment: Have you tried template literals?

Comment: Remember to remove the backslashes when you change to the backtick

Comment: Also you have whitespace in the URL you create. That is also not a good idea

Comment: [Please see the refactored script I made you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77776882/295783) - there were more issues than mentioned here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. In JS, you can execute expressions and put them in strings like so:

```js
console.log(`Function result: ${someFunction()}`);
```

There is one mistake in your syntax. You are using single quotes ('); you must use backticks (`) for strings using the "${}" syntax. Instead, use this:

```js
str = str + `<div class="card my-4 mx-4" style="width: 20.5rem;">\
                             <img src= `${item.thumbnail}` class="card-img-top" alt="Card image cap">\
                             <div class="card-body">\
                             <h5 class="card-title">${item.headline}</h5>\
                             <p class="card-text">'${item.trailText}'</p>\
                             <a href="${item.webUrl}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>\
                             </div>\
                             </div>`
```

These strings are called `Template Literals`. Learn more on this topic at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues

1. spaces in the URL
2. wrong use of quotes when trying to use template literals
3. You do not actually return the string

Here is a refactored script that can handle page changes and even changes to the query. The dates are calculated.

I use fetch since I do not know what `Request` you use. The fetch can be used in the browser and on the server if you use node.js version 19+

```js
const getDashedDate = date => date.toISOString().slice(0, 10); // yyyy-mm-dd

let currentPage = 0; // we increment on first load too

// stuff you may want to change

const apiKey = 'test'; // change to your key
const url = new URL('https://content.guardianapis.com/search?show-fields=trailText%2Cheadline%2Cthumbnail'); // base url

let query; // we need it here if you want to change it in the interface
const fromDate = new Date();
fromDate.setFullYear(fromDate.getFullYear() - 1, 0, 1); // Jan 1st last year
const toDate = new Date(); // now


const parms = new URLSearchParams(url.search); // construct a parameter object
parms.set('api-key',apiKey);
parms.set('from-date', getDashedDate(fromDate));
parms.set('to-date', getDashedDate(toDate));


const fetchNewsData = async(url) => { 
  let response = await fetch(url);
  if (!response.ok) {
    console.error("Fetch failed:", response.status);
    return null;
  }
  try { // See if we get valid JSON and can parse it into an array
    let jsonData = await response.json(); // get the object from the JSON 
    if (jsonData && Array.isArray(jsonData.response.results)) { // test it 
      return jsonData.response.results;
    } else {
      console.error("No valid 'results' in JSON response");
      return null;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error parsing JSON:", error);
    return null;
  }
};


const formatNews = newsData => { // expecting an array
  if (!newsData || newsData.length === 0) {
    return `<div class="card my-4 mx-4" style="width: 20.5rem;">No result for query ${query}, page ${page}</div>`;
  }
  return newsData.map((item,i) => `<div class="card my-4 mx-4" style="width: 20.5rem;">
    <img src="${item.fields.thumbnail}" class="card-img-top" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">${item.fields.headline}</h5>
      <p class="card-text">${item.fields.trailText}</p>
      <a href="${item.webUrl}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
    </div>
  </div>`).join('');
};

const GetNews = async(page) => {
  parms.set('q', query); // this will convert any space or special chars to valid URL content
  parms.set('page', page); // update the URL
  url.search = parms.toString();
  console.log(url.toString());
  const newsData = await fetchNewsData(url.toString());
  return formatNews(newsData); // formatNews handles null
};

const loadAndDisplayNews = async() => {
  query = document.getElementById('query').value; // make it possible for user to change

  currentPage++; // first load will have page 1
  try {
    const newsHtml = await GetNews(currentPage);
    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = newsHtml;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error loading news:", error);
    // Optionally, handle the error in the UI
  }
};




window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { // when the page has loaded
  document.getElementById('loadMoreNews').addEventListener('click', loadAndDisplayNews);
  loadAndDisplayNews(); // initial load
});
```

```html
<button id="loadMoreNews">Load More News</button>
<input type="hidden" id="query" value="sport" />

<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier and more secure to set your response items values directly to the DOM and not to a lengthy html string. But if you decide to stay with using a lengthy string, then I would make sure to use the String Template syntax from [Mozilla's MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for string interpolation.

Or you can manually update the DOM directly and avoid lengthy string concatenation.

```js
let img = document.getElementsByName('img')[0];
img.setAttribute("src", item.thumbnail);
```